# Real time map testing in apple device

Tags: manual-testing, ios

I have a driving school application to test which somewhat works like Uber. My question is how can I test the real time map in my ios application?
User will provide the Start and End point but how to be sure that application is tracking the correct activity in the map?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the application is supposed to do?

Comment: Its a app for driving school where instructor will decide a course for a driver and driver will have to drive in that course. the activity will be tracked using GPS on google maps. Its kind of mini Uber

Answer (score 2):

Positive Test case-
- Open Internet explorer/web-browser.
- Type www.maps.google.com and enter
- Check page is open.
- Place cursor in text box and type city/place name and click on 'Search 
Maps'.
- Check place is displayed in maps.
- Check for satellite view click on 'Satellite' button; should display view.
- check for live traffic click on 'Traffic' button; should display live traffic with 
traffic speed.
- Check for street view click on 'Street View' button and view should be 
displayed.
- check for business/address in area selected above-type business to 
find(e.g Pizza) ;should display pizza locations in that area.
- To check directions click on 'Get Directions' and type locations A and B 
and click on 'Get Directions';should display directions to reach B from A.

Negative Test Case-
- Type wrong web address in web-browser.
- Type wrong name of city/place in text box and click 'Search Maps';should 
display suggestions for correcting name.
- To get directions click on "get Directions' and type location A and leave 
location B blank and click on 'Get Directions';should display message' Enter 
location or right-click on map'.
- Type location A of one country and location B of other(e.g. location in India 
and location in USA);should display 'Could not calculate directions between A 
and B'

Comment: Its a app for driving school where instructor will decide a course for a driver and driver will have to drive in that course. the activity will be tracked using GPS on google maps. Its kind of mini Uber .Your answer doesn't fit because you said cases for map testing and not for driving application testing

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of tests you need to do. If it is UAT than you will have to leave your nice office and go out on a street.